# Dirac equation, $\alpha_i$, $\beta$ hermitian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation

The argument I've seen is the one given here: http://epx.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/~yhitoshi/particleweb/ptest-3.pdf under (3.10):

$$H=\vec{\alpha}\cdot(-i\vec{\nabla})+\beta m$$

$H$ is hermitian, $-i\vec{\nabla}$ is hermitian, so $\vec{\alpha},\beta$ are hermitian.

This is not convincing, because a hermitian operator being a sum of two operators does not imply that the two are also hermitian, for example in the harmonic oscillator, the position and momentum operators can be written as a sum or difference of the annihilation/creation operators, which are non-hermitian.

So is the presented argument wrong? Why are the $\alpha_i, \beta$ really hermitian?

Comment: Please include the relevant contents of the link into the question.

Comment: The reason is that hermicity condition must hold for each eigenvalues of $\hat{p}_{0}, \hat{p}_{\mu}$. Since $\alpha , \beta$ don't depend on coordinates, then due to hermicity of $i\nabla $ we have the statement.

Comment: I don't quite follow that, could you elaborate please?

Comment: This is much more convincing, consider turning this into answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its important to say that the Dirac equation cannot be derived using standard QM: it can be motivated, but ultimalely the definitive argument for/against its correction is a matter of experimental confirmation.

This means that the arguments that the link gives you in favour of the equation are just formal: they might seem very logical and unavoidable, but if the resulting equation doesnt work, its wrong.

I think its important to remember this, as we novice physicists tend to forget/ignore the infinite number of proposed equation, which felt very logical at the time, but soon ruled out by experiments. Dirac equation remained because it works. $\boldsymbol \alpha,\beta$ are hermitian because the resulting equation works.

That being said, we can give some arguments as to why $\boldsymbol \alpha,\beta$ **cannot** be non-hermitian: if we want a Hamiltonian like
$$
H=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol p+m\beta
$$
to be hermitian, then we are forced to take both $\boldsymbol \alpha$ and $\beta$ hermitian. One way of proving this is to see that $H$ must be hermitian regardless of the value of $m$. In particular, $H$ must be hermitian for massless particles, so
$$
H_\text{massless}=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol p
$$
must be hermitian. But as $\boldsymbol p$ is hermitian, the three matrices $\boldsymbol \alpha$ must be hermitian. As $\boldsymbol \alpha$ is independent of $m$, $\boldsymbol\alpha$ must also be hermitian in the massive case:
$$
H=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol p+m\beta
$$

Finally, as we already proved, the first term in the expression above is hermitian, so if $H$ is to be hermitian, the so must the term $m\beta$. This proves that $\beta$ must be hermitian.

Answer (score 2):

The Hilbert space in which the Dirac equation acts is a product of the infinite-dimensional space corresponding to position (or momentum) and a finite-dimensional spinor space, in which the matrices $\alpha_{j}$ and $\beta$ act.  We know the momentum operator is Hermitian, so we may look at a subspace for fixed $\vec{p}$; in order for $H$ to be Hermitian, the matrix $\vec{\alpha}\cdot\vec{p}+\beta m$ must be Hermitian in the finite-dimensional spinor space for every value of $\vec{p}$. This means that an arbitrary linear combination of the $\alpha_{j}$ and $\beta$ matrices is Hermitian, which is only possible if all four matrices are Hermitian themselves.